# Why won't this Perl DBI/DBD MySQL (MariaDB) connect to locahost work?

Tags: mysql, perl, mariadb, dbi

```
use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect ('DBI:mysql:host=localhost;database=test', 'user', 'password') 
   or die "failed to connect\n";
```

Results in an error message:

> DBI connect('host=localhost;database=test','user',...) failed: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061) at connect.pl line 3.

using: **DBI 1.641**, **perl v5.26.2** on **Windows 10** and running **MariaDB 10.2.14**

mysqld is running on the computer, and the server can be connected to with the standard "mysql test -u user -p" command

On another PC running **Windows 7** with a very similar setup - but with **DBI 1.636** - the connect() succeeds with the same perl code.  Is is possible that `DBI:mysql` and **Windows 10** aren't compatible?

Comment: Try to add `... 'user', 'password', {RaiseError=>1})`

Comment: @Michael: That has no effect on the behaviour of the `connect` call itself; only on subsequent calls on the resultant database handle (when the `connect` has worked).

Comment: Are you able to manually connect to specifically to `localhost` running `MySQL-client` on this device?

Comment: As stated in the question, the connection with the mysql command succeeds.  Adding '- h localhost' has no practical effect, as that is the default host for mysql.

Comment: still using DBI 1.641 (current verison), and updating DBD:mysql did not help

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a space after the word "connect", anyway...try this:

```
my $driver   = "mysql";
my $database = "DBname";
my $ip       = "localhost";
my $db       = "DBI:$driver:DBNAME:$ip:database=$database";
my $username = "mysqluser";
my $password = "mysqlpass";

my $cn = DBI->connect($db, $username, $password)
    or print "Couldn't connect to database: " . DBI->errstr . "\n\n";
```

Comment: Perl is generally free form.  Any whitespace between connect and the opening parenthesis is irrelevant. 
 
The code block fails, but it's no surprise - for one thing, it has "DBNAME" as a literal, but also "DBname" as the value of $database in the $db string..

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're using the wrong driver name in the connection string. Even though MariaDb it's a fork of MySql, it's not the same

So you need to use:

> 'DBI:**MariaDB**:host=...'

Full code would be:

> use DBI;
>
> my $dbh = DBI->connect ('DBI:MariaDB:host=localhost;database=test',
> 'user', 'password')     or die "failed to connect\n";

Source: https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::MariaDB