# Mysql Error 2003 (HY00): Can't connect to server after machine restart on Windows 10

Tags: mysql

I have installed Mysql v8.0.26 web community using the MSI installer for a class. It functions fine during regular use but I will run the `quit` command and closed the cmd prompt. Then shut down my machine, and when I turn it back on and try to reconnect to the server it gives me `ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost: 3306' (10061)` I've tried to troubleshoot using the documentation on the website with no luck. I'm wondering if anyone has any suggestions. The only workaround that I have is to reinstall MySQL.Forgive me if I am missing something; I'm fairly new to MySQL.

Comment: Ensure that the mysql service is running.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MYSQL - Cant connect to MYSQL server on 'localhost' (10061)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/385460/6381711)

Comment: Yes and no. I think it got me closer to finding out the issue. It seems my 3306 port is having issues opening. When I try to test the port it says it cannot be opened. I have tried updating the firewall to allow the port to open but it still doesn't work. I'm still trying to research the issue. It might still have something to do with the firewall.

Answer (score 0):

So after much research, it seems I have solved the issue. I had multiple Windows services on my machine for MySQL. What I think might of happened is they were all trying to connect to the same port and were failing because so. After I uninstalled MySQL, cleared the environment path, and removed the Windows services with the cmd command `sc delete "<service name>"` and then did a fresh install it worked. It worked even after a full shutdown of my machine.